# powershell -replace only write file on changes

Tags: powershell, regexp-replace

I'm doing some multiple regEX replacements in powershell on a large number of files and would like to only  write the file if any replacements were actually made.

For example if I do:

```
($_ | Get-Content-Raw) -Replace 'MAKEUPS', 'Makeup' -Replace '_MAKEUP', 'Makeup' -Replace 'Make up', 'Makeup' -Replace 'Make-up', 'Makeup' -Replace '"SELF:/', '"' | 
  Out-File $_.FullName -encoding ASCII
```

I only want to write the file if it found anything to replace. Is this possible, maybe with a count or boolean operation?

I did think maybe to check the length of the string before and after but was hoping for a more elegant solution, so I thought I'd ask the experts!

Comment: Create a regex string with the search words separated with `|` (the regex OR). Capture the content in a variable and perform a `if ($content -match $theRegexString) { # do the replacements}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that PowerShell's [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator passes the input string through *as-is* if no replacements were performed:

```bash
# <# some Get-ChildItem command #> ... | ForEach-Object {

  # Read the input file in full, as a single string.
  $originalContent = $_ | Get-Content -Raw

  # *Potentially* perform replacements, depending on whether the search patterns are found.
  $potentiallyModifiedContent =
    $originalContent -replace 'MAKEUPS', 'Makeup' -replace '_MAKEUP', 'Makeup' -replace 'Make up', 'Makeup' -replace 'Make-up', 'Makeup' -replace '"SELF:/', '"'

  # Save, but only if modifications were made.
  if (-not [object]::ReferenceEquals($originalContent, $potentiallyModifiedConent)) {
    Set-Content -NoNewLine -Encoding Ascii -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Value $potentiallyModifiedConent
  }

# }
```

- `[object]::ReferenceEquals()` tests for *reference equality*, i.e. whether the two strings represent the *exact same string instance*, which makes the comparison very efficient (no need to look at the *content* of the strings).
- [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) rather than [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) is used to write the output file, which is preferable for performance reasons with input that is made up of *strings* already.

  - `-NoNewLine` is needed to prevent a *trailing newline* from getting appended to the output file.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, even if I take out all replacements the ReferenceEquals test reports not equal and the file is updated

Comment: @Puck, are you using the right variables? Try the following simplified example, which works for me in both Windows PowerShell and PowerShell Core (outputs `$true`): `$old = 'foo'; $new = $old -replace 'x' -replace 'y'; [object]::ReferenceEquals($old, $new)`

Comment: Foreach-Object { Write-Host $_.FullName # -NoNewLine 
  $originalContent = $_ | Get-Content -Raw
  $potentiallyModifiedContent = $originalContent
  
  if (-not [object]::ReferenceEquals($originalContent, $potentiallyModifiedConent))
   {
   Set-Content -NoNewLine -Encoding Ascii -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Value $potentiallyModifiedConent
   Write-Host " fixed"
   }
  else
   {
   Write-Host " no replacements needed"
   }
}

Comment: @Puck, you cannot paste multi-line code in comments, which makes it very hard to read. From what I can tell, there's no attempt to call `-replace` in what you pasted. Did the simple example from my previous comment not work for you? If it did, it implies that the answer should work.

Comment: Yes your simple example works. the code i pasted was after removing all -replace operations so both strings should be equal but the test fails.  I cannot seem to enter a return when posting a comment, which makes it hard to show my code. I pretty much copied and pasted your original answer into my script the changes the replacements.

Comment: @Puck, you have a _typo_: `$potentiallyModifiedConent` -> `$potentiallyModifiedContent`. You could catch such typos by placing `Set-StrictMode -Version 1` at the top of your script (see [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode)) or use Visual Studio Code  with the PowerShell extension for developing your scripts, which would highlight such a problem during editing.

Comment: As for formatting in comments: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting - in short: you can only use _inline_ code formatting (`\`...\``) with no support for line breaks. Unlike in posts, there must be _no whitespace_ after the opening and before the closing delimiter. _Multi_-`\`` delimiters for support of embedded `\`` chars. are supported (e.g. `\`\`"\`n"\`\``). Unlike in posts, ``\`` can alternatively be used to escape `\``, which, due to the no-whitespace requirement, is a must if you want to produce something like `\`enclosed\``. To produce a formatted ``\`` alone, use `\`\`\\`\``

Comment: Typos, that'll do it.  Thank you for your patience, I'm using Notepad++, maybe I should read more...

Comment: Glad we worked it out, Puck. Here are links to get you started: The editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience, across platforms, is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), combined with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the script block feature added in ps6 to set a variable when a replacement takes place, then return the replacement string.

```
$replaced = $false
$content = (Get-content -raw $file) -replace "(make-up|makeups|make up|...)", { 
  # $replaced = $true
  Set-Variable replaced $true -Scope 1
  return "Makeup"
} -replace "SELF:/", { 
  Set-Variable replaced $true -Scope 1
  # $replaced = $true
  return '"'
}

If ($replaced){
  Set-content -path $file -value $content
}
```

In older versions of PowerShell, you might check the content length and if they're the same do a comparison... I wouldn't do a match to see if replacement is needed, that would be a lot more expensive...

```
$original = (Get-content -raw $file)
$content = ($original) -replace "(make-up|makeups|make up|...)", "Make up"

If (($original.length -ne $content.length) -or ($original -ne $content)) {
   Set-content ...
}
```

Comment: Great idea, using `-replace` with a `scriptblock`! Note that in older versions of PowerShell you could use `[regex]::Replace( $text, 'pattern', {scriptblock} )` to achieve the same. The only difference is that the `scriptblock` runs in a child scope, so you can't set `$replaced` directly. Modify it through a reference or `Set-Variable replaced $true -Scope 1`.

Comment: While script-block-based `-replace` operations are very flexible, they are also expensive.
To compare the before and after strings _by content_, it's better to use `-cne` to also detect replacements that result in case variations only. At least hypothetically, even that can
miss modifications, if they result in a _linguistically_ equivalent string.
Fortunately, there's a much simpler solution: check the before and after strings for _reference equality_.
Also, `-NoNewLine` should be added to the `Set-Content` call, so as to prevent an extra newline from getting appended.